# How to resolve oauth.signpost.exception.oauthcommunicationexception twitter android?

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to intigrtae twitter in my app.

I fallow all the following link.
[enter link description here](http://blog.tarams.com/index.php/2012/twitter-integration-with-android-app-using-oauth/)

I don't what i did wrong.

I am getting  the following error

10-30 08:08:19.838: W/System.err(14272): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 307 (Temporary Redirect)
10-30 08:08:19.838: W/System.err(14272):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
10-30 08:08:19.838: W/System.err(14272):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)

I google somany to resolve the issue.

But i didn't find the solution.

If any one knoe how to resolve this,
Please help me